# Amazon MWS Connection Refused FeedSubmit

Tags: php, curl, amazon-mws

Im trying to submit a feed to MWS to update inventory using amazon PHP SDK.

Here my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>MY_MERCHANT_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
        <SKU>MY_SKU</SKU>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        <FulfillmentLatency>1</FulfillmentLatency>
    </Inventory>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

And my PHP code:

```
$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET, CONFIG_FEEDS, APP_NAME, APP_VERSION);

    $feedHandle = @fopen('php://memory', 'rw+');
    fwrite($feedHandle, XML_STRING);
    rewind($feedHandle);

    $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest();
    $request->setMerchant(MERCHANT_ID);
    $request->setMarketplaceIdList(["id" => [MARKET_PLACE_1, MARKET_PLACE_2, MARKET_PLACE_3]]);
    $request->setFeedType($feedType);
    $request->setContentMd5(base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true)));
    rewind($feedHandle);
    $request->setPurgeAndReplace(false);
    $request->setFeedContent($feedHandle);

    rewind($feedHandle);
    $response = $service->submitFeed($request);
```

When i run the code i get an empty error response:

```
Caught Exception: Internal Error 
Response Status Code: 0 
Error Code: 
Error Type: 
Request ID: 
XML: 
RequestId: , 
ResponseContext: , 
Timestamp: 
ResponseHeaderMetadata:
```

I activated curl to show errors and it says:

```
Failed to connect to mws.amazonservices.com.mx port 80: Connection refused
```

I read about the problem and saw answers about changing the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option which i tried modifiying that option in the function inside the class that sets the default configuration for Client.php as this:

```
private function getDefaultCurlOptions() {
return array (
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $this->config['UserAgent'],
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => array ($this, 'headerCallback'),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
);
```

And also tried to add my certificate which i just obtained from Mozilla and set the VERIFYPEER to true as this:

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO         => __DIR__ . "/../../../../../cacert.pem"
```

But no success. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized i was passing the URL in CONFIG_FEEDS while creating the client to connect without httpS :)